# Как написать скрипт переводчик для сайта на jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, replace

Есть [сайт](http://avtousta.ucoz.com/forum).
Как сделать, чтобы при входе на сайт один текст изменился на другой.
Допустим, на сайте есть такие слово **ФОРУМ, ТЕМЫ, ОТВЕТЫ**.
При загрузке страницы эти слова переводилось на это **FORUM, TEMALAR, CAVABLAR**

Я написал вот такой скрипт, но почему-то он работает не корректно.
Вся страница переводится в кашу :)

```
<script>
 $('body').each(function(){
     var $this = $(this);
     var t = $this.text();
     $this.html(t.replace('Форум','Forum')
        .replace('Темы', 'Mövzular'));
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Сварганил подобным образом, можно вносить сколь угодно переводов.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>titile</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>

 </style>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function(){

   var obj = {
    "Форум": 'Forum',
    "Темы": 'Temalar',
    "Ответы": 'Cavablar'
   }

   var html = $('body').html();

   for (key in obj) {
    html = html.replace(key, obj[key]);
   }

   $('body').html(html);

  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="">Форум</a>

<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Темы</td>
 </tr>
</table>


<span>Ответы</span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но почему то не работает на сайте, вы запихнули их в тег **<a>** а умнея на сайте эти текст находится по разных тегах **<td> <div> <span>**  и.т.д  я для примера в скрипте тег **a**  менял на тег **td** но все равно не работает. Здесь работает а на моем сайте не работает,   [вот сайт](http://avtousta.ucoz.com/forum/) ваш скрипт поставил до после **HEAD**  вниз страницу, верх страницу все равно не работает